# mysql find missing items

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table with the following structure

```
mysql> describe stock_prices;
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| code                | varchar(16) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| pricelist           | varchar(10) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| settlement_discount | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| overal_discount     | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sale                | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price_blob          | longtext    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

when i run this query

```
mysql> SELECT pricelist, count(pricelist) as dup from stock_prices group by pricelist having dup>1 order by dup;
+-----------+------+
| pricelist | dup  |
+-----------+------+
| GMBH      | 1843 |
| DISTCART  | 2241 |
| DISTSTD   | 2241 |
| CART      | 2242 |
| USSD      | 2242 |
| SPCA      | 2242 |
| SPCB      | 2242 |
| SPCC      | 2242 |
| EUCN      | 2242 |
| STD       | 2242 |
| EUSD      | 2242 |
| USCN      | 2242 |
+-----------+------+
12 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

all the pricelist items should have the same values, but GMBH has 399 less and DISTCART and DISTSTD have 1 less.

basically, i have `code` that does not have a pricelist entry.

when i run:

```
mysql> SELECT code, count(code) as dup from stock_prices group by code having dup>1 order by dup;
+-------------+-----+
| code        | dup |
+-------------+-----+
| XN44-CH2    |   9 |
| XN23-MGY1   |  11 |
| XN24-CH2    |  11 |
| XN25-VWH1   |  11 |
| XN36-BL2    |  11 |
| XN36-CH3    |  11 |
| XN37-BL3    |  11 |
| XN38-BC3    |  11 |
| XN38-CE3    |  11 |
....
```

so in this case `XN44-CH2` is missing 3 codes and `XN23-MGY1` is missing 1 code

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(pricelist) FROM stock_prices WHERE pricelist = 'GMBH';
+------------------+
| COUNT(pricelist) |
+------------------+
|             1843 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

what would be the correct way to find out what the missing pricelists for each is?

any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Please add some example data of the original table.

Comment: What is the result if you do this? `SELECT COUNT(pricelist) FROM stock_prices WHERE pricelist = 'GMBH'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is a reference table for all the price lists and one for all the codes, you could do something like this in standard SQL:

```
SELECT
  p.pricelist,
  c.code
FROM
  pricelists AS p
CROSS JOIN
  codes AS c

EXCEPT

SELECT
  pricelist,
  code
FROM
  stock_prices
;
```

That is, get all the combinations of the existing pricelists and codes and subtract those that are present in `stock_prices`. The result would be the missing pairs.

As MySQL doesn't support `EXCEPT`, you could implement the same logic with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  p.pricelist,
  c.code
FROM
  pricelists AS p
CROSS JOIN
  codes AS c
LEFT JOIN
  stock_prices AS s ON p.pricelist = s.pricelist
                   AND c.code = s.code
WHERE s.id IS NULL
;
```

If you do not have those reference tables, you could replace them with derived tables in this way:

```
pricelists  ==>  (SELECT DISTINCT pricelist FROM stock_prices)

codes  ==>  (SELECT DISTINCT code FROM stock_prices)
```

And the query would then look like this:

```
SELECT
  p.pricelist,
  c.code
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT pricelist FROM stock_prices) AS p
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT code FROM stock_prices) AS c
LEFT JOIN
  stock_prices AS s ON p.pricelist = s.pricelist
                   AND c.code = s.code
WHERE s.id IS NULL
;
```